# Как в PyQt5 подключить микроконтроллер Arduino через USB после того, как main.py уже был запущен на выполнение

Tags: python, pyqt5

Приведенный код работает следующим образом. После запуска ***main.py*** идет проверка подключения Arduino к ПК по USB. Если не подключен, то выводится сообщение о том, что *"Микроконтроллер не подключен"*. Приходится его подключать и **перезапускать программу**.

1. Как можно подключать/отключать Arduino **без перезапуска программы** c графическим интерфейсом на PyQt5?
2. Я заметил, что окно отображается мгновенно, если микроконтроллер не подключен. В противном случае окно полностью отображается только после того, как подключенный микроконтроллер свяжется с PyQt5, а это может длиться секунд 5. Как отобразить окно быстрее?

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from pyfirmata2 import Arduino


class New(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("form_usb.ui", self)

        self.TEXT.setText("Микроконтроллер подключен")

    def usb_off(self):
        self.TEXT.setText('Подключите микроконтроллер и перезапустите программу')

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)
        # sys.exit()  # <--- добавил для остановки процессов в IDE,
        # т.к. в случае выхода из программы остается гореть светодиод, если он был зажжен


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()

    # -##--- Автоопределение микроконтроллера ---##- #
    try:
        board = Arduino(Arduino.AUTODETECT)

    except:
        window.usb_off()
        print('Serial port не обнаружен.')

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***form_usb.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>654</width>
    <height>319</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">
</string>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="modal">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>601</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>16777215</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>GroupBox</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="TEXT">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>12</x>
      <y>28</y>
      <width>571</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Следуя комментарию от  insolor добавил кнопку переподключения Arduino. У меня очень мало опыта в написании подобной логики. И как делать подключение не в основном потоке, а в отдельном - я пока не понимаю. Чтобы понять это, мне нужен мой код, исправленный специалистом.

***Версия с кнопкой***

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from pyfirmata2 import Arduino


class New(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("form_usb.ui", self)

        self.CONNECT.clicked.connect(self.usb_on)
        self.logic = 0
        self.TEXT.setText("Микроконтроллер подключен")

    def usb_on(self):
        if self.logic == 1:
            self.board(True)

    def usb_off(self):
        self.logic = 1
        self.TEXT.setText('Подключите микроконтроллер и перезапустите программу')

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)
        # sys.exit()  # <--- добавил для остановки процессов в IDE,
        # т.к. в случае выхода из программы остается гореть светодиод, если он был зажжен


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()

    # -##--- Автоопределение микроконтроллера ---##- #
    try:
        board = Arduino(Arduino.AUTODETECT)

    except:
        window.usb_off()
        print('Serial port не обнаружен.')

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***form_usb.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>654</width>
    <height>319</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">
</string>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="modal">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>601</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>16777215</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>GroupBox</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="TEXT">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>12</x>
      <y>28</y>
      <width>571</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="CONNECT">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>520</x>
     <y>180</y>
     <width>93</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Перезапуск</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>150</y>
     <width>341</width>
     <height>91</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Кнопка перезапуска Arduino по USB</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: Окно с кнопкой]

---

Не знал, что PyQt настолько крут, что может работать с serial port.
Ответ в этом видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGv7qOlzzgQ

Comment: 2 - подключение делать не в основном потоке, а в отдельном. 1 - сделать кнопку "переподключиться", в которой запускается (также в отдельном потоке) `board = Arduino(Arduino.AUTODETECT)`

Answer (score 1):

Не знал, что PyQt настолько крут, что может работать с serial port. Больше нет нужды использовать PyFirmata. Все разъяснения на Ютуб канале "Заметки Ардуинщика"

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("USB.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('New')

        self.openB.clicked.connect(self.onOpen)
        self.closeB.clicked.connect(self.onClose)

        self.serial = QSerialPort()
        self.serial.setBaudRate(115200)
        portList = []
        ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
        for port in ports:
            portList.append(port.portName())
        print(portList)
        self.comL.addItems(portList)

    def onOpen(self):
        print('on')
        self.serial.setPortName(self.comL.currentText())
        self.serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    def onClose(self):
        print('close')
        self.serial.close()

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***USB.ui***

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>208</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>331</width>
      <height>121</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Открытие / закрытие порта</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="comL"/>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="openB">
       <property name="text">
        <string>OPEN</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="closeB">
       <property name="text">
        <string>CLOSE</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

***Скетч для Arduino***

```
// аналог пины
#define POT 0
#define THERM 1
#define PHOTO 2
#define JOYX 6
#define JOYY 7

// дигит пины
#define SRV_PIN 2
#define BTN 3
#define MOS 4
#define LED_R 5
#define LED_G 6
#define RELAY 10
#define LED_B 11

#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;

#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// 0x27 или 0x3f
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);


#include "thermistorMinim.h";
thermistor therm(THERM, 10000, 3950);

#include "EncButton.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "AsyncStream.h"  // асинхронное чтение сериал
AsyncStream<50> serial(&Serial, ';');   // указываем обработчик и стоп символ

EncButton<EB_TICK, BTN> btn;
bool flag = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  servo.attach(SRV_PIN);
  pinMode(13, 1);
  pinMode(LED_R, 1);
  pinMode(LED_G, 1);
  pinMode(LED_B, 1);
  pinMode(MOS, 1);
  pinMode(RELAY, 1);
}

// с ардуино на пк, терминтаор \n
// 0,потенц,фоторез,термистор
// 1,кнопка
// 2,joyx,joyy

// с пк на ардуино, терминтаор ;
// 0,лед 13
// 1,r,g,b
// 2,angle
// 3,fan
// 4,relay
// 5,text

void loop() {
  parsing();

  btn.tick();
  static uint32_t tmr = 0;
  if (millis() - tmr > 100) {
    tmr = millis();
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.print(analogRead(POT));
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.print(analogRead(PHOTO));
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println(therm.getTempAverage(), 2);
  }

  static uint32_t tmr2 = 0;
  if (millis() - tmr2 > 50) {
    tmr2 = millis();
    Serial.print(2);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.print(analogRead(JOYX));
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println(analogRead(JOYY));
  }

  if (btn.isClick()) {
    flag = !flag;
    Serial.print(1);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println(flag);
  }
}

// функция парсинга, опрашивать в лупе
void parsing() {
  if (serial.available()) {
    Parser data(serial.buf, ',');  // отдаём парсеру
    int ints[10];           // массив для численных данных
    data.parseInts(ints);   // парсим в него

    switch (ints[0]) {
      case 0: digitalWrite(13, ints[1]);
        break;
      case 1:
        analogWrite(LED_R, ints[1]);
        analogWrite(LED_G, ints[2]);
        analogWrite(LED_B, ints[3]);
        break;
      case 2:
        servo.write(ints[1]);
        break;
      case 3:
        digitalWrite(MOS, ints[1]);
        break;
      case 4:
        digitalWrite(RELAY, ints[1]);
        break;
      case 5:
        data.split();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.home();
        lcd.print(data[1]);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```
````